# Why does the delegate of an UIAlertView not work?

Tags: ios, swift

When I use my class `AlertView` for displaying an `UIAlertView`, I set the delegate to this class object and expect `alertView:clickedButtonAt` to run, but when I click abutton on the `UIAlertView`, it doesn't work. Why? Thanks!

```
import UIKit
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window : UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow()
        window!.rootViewController = UIViewController()
        window!.rootViewController!.view.backgroundColor = .blue
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        let a = AlertView()
        a.show()
        return true
    }

}
class AlertView : UIViewController,UIAlertViewDelegate{
    var done : ((_ buttonIndex: Int)->Void)?
    func show(){
        var createAccountErrorAlert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView()

        createAccountErrorAlert.delegate = self

        createAccountErrorAlert.title = "Oops"
        createAccountErrorAlert.message = "Could not create account!"
        createAccountErrorAlert.addButton(withTitle: "Dismiss")
        createAccountErrorAlert.addButton(withTitle: "Retry")

        createAccountErrorAlert.show()

    }
    func alertView(_ alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAt buttonIndex: Int){
            print("Why delegate of alert view does not work?")
    }
}
```

Comment: UIAlertView should not be used. You should be using UIAlertController instead. UIAlertView was deprecated in iOS9.

Comment: thanks for your attention ,I just edit and fix old legacy code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring your `UIAlertView` instance as a local variable and that way, it does not have a reference. Make it a global variable, so the delegate method could execute properly.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that it is related to memory management issue. `createAccountErrorAlert` has been declared as local variable into `show()` method, which leads to let the lifetime of the variable is dependent to the lifetime of executing the method.

The **solution** is to declare `createAccountErrorAlert` as an instance variable, as follows:

```
class AlertView : UIViewController,UIAlertViewDelegate{
    var done : ((_ buttonIndex: Int)->Void)?
    var createAccountErrorAlert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView()

    func show(){
        createAccountErrorAlert.delegate = self

        createAccountErrorAlert.title = "Oops"
        createAccountErrorAlert.message = "Could not create account!"
        createAccountErrorAlert.addButton(withTitle: "Dismiss")
        createAccountErrorAlert.addButton(withTitle: "Retry")

        createAccountErrorAlert.show()

    }
    func alertView(_ alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAt buttonIndex: Int){
        print("Why delegate of alert view does not work?")
    }
}
```

***Remark***: I would highly recommend to use [UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller) instead of [UIAlertView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertview):

> UIAlertView is deprecated in iOS 8. (Note that UIAlertViewDelegate is
>   also deprecated.) To create and manage alerts in iOS 8 and later,
>   instead use  UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of alert.